# Ajax submit with specific IDs in execute still submits entire form

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

As far as I understood, specifying IDs in the `execute` of an `f:ajax` tag should limit the fields which are posted to the server.

```
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="one" value="#{manageSettingsBean.testOne}"/>
        <h:inputText id="two" value="#{manageSettingsBean.testTwo}"/>

        <h:commandButton value="Multi test" action="#{maintainEntityAction.multi(manageSettingsBean.testOne, manageSettingsBean.testTwo)}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this one"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

In this case, I'd expect that only the first `inputText` would be submitted.

On examining the form data in Chrome's Network tab, however, I see

`j_idt13=j_idt13&j_idt13%3Aone=One&j_idt13%3Atwo=Two&javax.faces.ViewState=-8624538035389330252%3A2147742525648157763&javax.faces.source=j_idt13%3Aj_idt14&javax.faces.partial.event=click&javax.faces.partial.execute=j_idt13%3Aj_idt14%20j_idt13%3Aone&javax.faces.behavior.event=action&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true`

Which contains both components, with their default values (of `"One"` and `"Two"`).

```
j_idt13:one=One
j_idt13:two=Two
```

The first component is specified in the `javax.faces.partial.execute`, so it is the only one that is updated, but both fields do seem to be submitted. I'm doing the partial submit as part of a large form to avoid posting up too much data, but the benefit would appear to be lost if the entire form is still being submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` attribute has no relation to the submitting of fields or not. It influences their processing on the server. So in this regard your expectation is wrong and everything behaves as expected.

PrimeFaces has introduced a `partialSubmit` for this that uses their `process` attribute (their counterpart of `execute`) to limit what is actually submitted.

Based on this I created some code for another question [<f:ajax render="@none" execute="@this"> and reducing submitted post data size in large form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366490/fajax-render-none-execute-this-and-reducing-submitted-post-data-size-in) that makes this work on plain JSF as well and at the same time I submitted a [feature request to OmniFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/394) to add the same functionality to the OmniFaces `o:form`. They improved it a little and added it to the upcoming release which you can already try as a [3.0-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/3.0-SNAPSHOT/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Omnifaces isn't completely compatible with JBoss EAP6's module structure, so we can't go that route, but we'll try out the plain JSF.